# auto increment id not inserted

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using simple MySQL code to insert data from a form with auto_increment id, it works fine on local host but not on server.

this is the code I am using

```
 $myvar=$_POST['var'];
 //Insert data into mysql table
$sql="INSERT INTO mytable(id,myvar) VALUES ('','$myvar')";
```

in local host phpmyadmin data is inserted in table but on server phpmyadmin data is not inserted in table. In my localhost I am using `XAMPP` whereas phpmyadmin on IIS server.
What setting should I do in phpmyadmin on server so that id is automatically inserted with auto increment, I know I can use `mysql_insert_id()` to insert id but in lots of file i have used this type of code which I cannot change. I want the same setting as `XAMPP` that can take this type of code easily.

Comment: Make sure your DB column is having auto increment property in IIS Server

Comment: Why not you use phpmyadmin to make it auto_increment?

Comment: On a tangential note, the way you are using $myvar could lead to a SQL injection attack. I am hoping you are taking care of that in some way..

Comment: [Still using `mysql_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php), even though it's been deprecated... If it weren't dangerous and flawed in many ways, I'd admire your courrage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

auto increment inserts id itself so you don't need to pass it through code

```
$sql="INSERT INTO mytable(myvar) VALUES ('$myvar')";
```

or you can do this

```
$sql="INSERT INTO mytable(id,myvar) VALUES (NULL,'$myvar')";
```

if you want want to manually insert id for some reason

```
$sql="INSERT INTO mytable(id,myvar) VALUES (10,'$myvar')";
```

Answer (score 7):

You as inserting '' into auto-increment id. just insert other fields and MySQL handles the auto-increment column.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO mytable(id,myvar) VALUES ('','$myvar')";
```

should be

```
$sql="INSERT INTO mytable(myvar) VALUES ('$myvar')";
```

Comment: If the value cannot be omitted, it shouldn't be an empty string, but NULL.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last of *all the rows* in the table, then this is finally the time where `MAX(id)` is the right answer! :) kind of.

```
SELECT fields FROM mytable BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

will get the last id then increment it to 1 // add this value to id in insert statement

or 
if you have a **autoincrement** column change it to

```
$sql="INSERT INTO mytable(id,myvar) VALUES ('','$myvar')";
```

to

```
$sql="INSERT INTO mytable(myvar) VALUES ('$myvar')";
```

Comment: Actually that `MAX(id)` approach will lead to errors because after that value has been determined, a different process might add a new dataset with exactly that ID. It is not safe in a system with concurrent access.

Answer (score 1):

if still you are getting the error

first check, in the server your id column must marked as auto_increment.data type should be int.
if it is ok then

```
insert into mytable(myvar) values('test');
```

and try to use prepared statements to avoid the sql injection.  Thanks.
hope this may usefull for you.

Answer (score 0):

First check your table Structure Property by applying query:

desc mytable (or) show create table mytable.

Check auto increment property been set for column id.

If yes means don't need to pass id in insert query.

Just write a query as :-

**$sql="INSERT INTO mytable(myvar) VALUES ('$myvar')";**